# Wpf Image Button doesnt set icon at runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, imagebutton, modern-ui

Heres my code

[image]
Here is my design view

[image]

It seems fine

However when I run the program I got this

[image]

Where is my Plus icon? I set order "Bring into front" also

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the **Build Action** of your image is set to **Resource**.

Comment: `<Image Source="Resources/Images/add.png"/>` should work. The relative path doesn't make sense (actually it isn't even one because of the leading `/`).

Comment: And please do not post a screenshot of your code. Add it as text to your question. Indentation by 4 characters will care for proper code formatting.

Comment: Thanks A lot Clemens. :) It worked

Comment: Clemens I added code hovewer formatting didnt work (seems working but didnt allow me to post the code) I think there is a problem about it.

Comment: Please, instead of using a relative path, use your image as resource. "pack://application:,,,/Images/add.png"

Comment: @Ugur The `pack://application:,,,/` prefix is automatically added by the XAML parser, and hence not strictly necessary in XAML. So, `Resources/Images/add.png` is implicitly converted to `pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/add.png`.

Comment: Today Its my learning day :) Thanks a lot :))